# Recording binay data with pyserial and convert the data back to a readable output

Tags: python, pandas, binary, sensors, pyserial

I am trying to record binary sensor data with pyserial and convert it back to a readable output.
I recorded the data as a bytearray. This is a short example:

bytearray(b'~P\x1a\x004>e\x7f!>\xa2\xfa\x1dA\xff\x05]\xbd\xf5\xe6\x88\xbc!\x8eL\xbc1\xd5IV~Q\x1a\x004>bC\x1b>^j\x1dA00\xee<\xba\xf8\x88\xbb!\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x00O\xc7~R\x1a\x009>\x98k\x1a>Y\xf2\x1dA\x0f\x14*=\xa9\xb1\x88\xbb!\x8e\xaa<\xa9\xb1\xe38~S\x1a\x00;>\xa9\x0f\x19>HN\x1dA>\x02\x99=\xe4\x9f\xee\xbc\xba\xf8\x88;!\x8e\xa5`~T\x1a\x00>>\xccW\x1c>j\x96\x1cA\xae\xfb\x88\xbc!\x8e\x88;!\x8e\x08\xbd!\x8e\xb1%~U\x1a\x006>x_\x19>HN\x1dA\xaf\x19\x88\xbc!\x8e\x08\xbd!\x8e\xaa\xbc\xa9\xb1<c~V\x1a\x004>e\x7f\x15>#\xca\x1dA00\x80=>\x05\xcc\xbc1\xd5\x88;!\x8eZ\x05~W\x1a\x00<>\xbb\xb3\x17>6\xaa\x1dAP.\x88\xbb!\x8e\xaa<\xa9\xb1*=\xa9\xb1(;~X\x1a\x00?>\xdd\xfb!>\x9e\x82\x1dA_\x0f\x88\xbc!\x8e\x08\xbd!\x8e\x08\xbc!\x8es\x1f~Y\x1a\x00A>\xf1\xdb\x1e>\x80\xb2\x1cA\xae\xfb\x88\xbb!\x8e\x08<!\x8e\x08\xbd!\x8e\xc0\xde~Z\x1a\x00;>\xa9\x0f\x14>\x11&\x1cAn\xff\x08<!\x8e\x88;!\x8e\x08\xbc!\x8e>:~[\x1a\x00;>\xa9\x0f\x10>\xed\xa1\x1dA\xa0)\x08<!\x8e\xee\xbc\xba\xf8;\xbdm\xc3\x1a\x10~\\\x1a\x00A>\xf1\xdb\x19>E\x12\x1dA0!L\xbc1\xd5\x08\xbc!\x8e\x08<!\x8e\xd3\x0f~]\x1a\x003>V\x17\x10>\xed\xa1\x1dA\xc16\x88;!\x8e\xcc<1\xd5\x88\xbc!\x8e\x07\x05~^\x1a\x00A>\xf1\xdb\x10>\xeae\x1cA\x1e\xf5\xee\xbc\xba\xf8\x08<!\x8e\x88;!\x8e\x8dh~_\x1a\x00<>\xbb\xb3\x12>\xfeE\x1dA\xff\x05\x88<!\x8e\x08\xbd!\x8e\x19=\xe4\x9f\xcfd~`\x1a\x004>g\xbb\x10>\xed\xa1\x1dA "\x08\xbc!\x8e\x08\xbc!\x8e\xaa\xbc\xa9\xb1M\xc8~a\x1a\x009>\x98k\x12>\xfb\t\x1dA0!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08<!\x8e\x88\xbb!\x8e\x12\xb4~b\x1a\x008>\x8a\x03\x1c>j\x96\x1dA\xef\x15]\xbd\xf5\xe6\x19=\xe4\x9f\x08\xbd!\x8e\xa3Z~c\x1a\x007>\x85\x8b\x12>\x00\x82\x1dA>\x02\x08<!\x8e\xcc<1\xd5\x08\xbc!\x8e\x84\x11~d\x1a\x00<>\xbb\xb3\x13>\x0f\xea\x1cAn\xff\x08<!\x8e\xcc\xbc1\xd5*=\xa9\xb1@6~e\x1a\x00<>\xbd\xef\x14>\x11&\x1dA\xef\x15\x88\xbb!\x8e\x88\xbc!\x8e\x88\xbb!\x8e\xcc\xa9~f\x1a\x00>>\xccW\x1c>j\x96\x1dA\x0f\x14\x80\xbd>\x05\x88<!\x8e\xcc<1\xd5Y\xe1~g\x1a\x00E>\x13$!>\xa0\xbe\x1dA\xb0(\xaa\xbc\xa9\xb1*=\xa9\xb1\xee<\xba\xf8R\xa1~h\x1a\x00@>\xe07\x19>HN\x1dA\xe04\xee<\xba\xf8\xee<\xba\xf8\x88;!\x8eI3~i\x1a\x00<>\xbd\xef\x19>HN\x1dAO\x10*=\xa9\xb1L<1\xd5\xee<\xba\xf8$f~j\x1a\x00@>\xe07%>\xc5B\x1cA\xae\xfb\x88;!\x8e\x08\xbc!\x8eL\xbc1\xd5\xa4\x12~k\x1a\x004>bC)>\xec\x02\x1cAn\xff\x88\xbc!\x8e*=\xa9\xb1\x08\xbc!\x8e\xe0\xb1~l\x1a\x00->\x1d\xb3,>\x0fK\x1dA\xcf\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08<!\x8e\xee<\xba\xf8\x8b\x15~m\x1a\x00,>\x0c\x0f">\xa7r\x1dA\xef\x06L<1\xd5\xcc\xbc1\xd5\x08<!\x8e\x1eA~n\x1a\x005>q\xab >\x91V\x1cAm\xe1\xcc<1\xd5\x08=!\x8e\xcc\xbc1\xd5\xb4\x8d~o\x1a\x00,>\x0c\x0f.>"+\x1dA\x8f\x1b]\xbd\xf5\xe6\xaa\xbc\xa9\xb1;\xbdm\xc3\xcaN~p\x1a\x004>bC">\xa56\x1dAN\x01\x08<!\x8e\x88\xbc!\x8e\x19=\xe4\x9f\n')bytearray

Now I need to convert the data back to a readable out. The structure should look like:

1. Byte: SYNC = 0x7E
2. Byte = sample counter 0...255
3. - 4. Byte = Package length

Followed by:

```
3 * float_32 (IACC) -> Sensor1

3 * float_32 (IOMG) -> Sensor2

2 Byte CRC16
```

Thank your for the help.

Comment: what sensor is it?  generally I find there is a library to decode sensors provided by manufacturer.  then it's simple to sample and append to a dataframe at appropriate intervals

Comment: It is an accelerometer and a gyroscope from an IMU.

Comment: I have temp & humidity sensors connected to a RPi, also had them connected to an Arduino - using information in pages like this https://makersportal.com/blog/2019/11/11/raspberry-pi-python-accelerometer-gyroscope-magnetometer#interfacing I was able to simplify and use existing utilities for getting data from sensor